# It is rated to 20A @ 28VDC, but I was wondering with a reduced current (16A), it can withstand a higher voltage

Tags: current, switches, toggle-switch

Goal:  I am looking to buy a switch that handles 16A @ 85VDC.  This switch needs to be a SP3T switch so I am not sure a relay can do this.  The switch will move between a PU/PD/and load and is a LS switch.

I am looking at a switch such as this:
https://www.arrow.com/en/products/2nt1-12/honeywell

It is rated to 20A @ 28VDC, but I was wondering if due to the reduced current, it can withstand a higher voltage.  I was trying to view the specification to determine if this is possible, but I am having a hard time understanding the spec to figure this out.

My feeling is at 16A it can go up, but probably not by a factor of 3, can someone help me determine this?

Comment: This question has tons of duplicates, with relays, switches, connectors, etc etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [datasheet](http://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/9802a035759bdfe08661218426cf5f5c4cbbb19b/nt_series.pdf) says it is rated at 750mA at 115VDC *resistive*.

[image]

If your load is inductive, it will not be good even for that.

The DC rating is partly based on how far the contacts open to stop the arcing (less of a problem when switching AC current). As you can see, somewhere between 28VDC and 115VDC it becomes a *major* issue, even for a resistive load.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  That is what I was trying to understand. I did not understand that table.  Now I see it is a inductive load, resistive load, or lamp.  This is the answer I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The current rating is produced by the thickness and conductiveness of the material, the voltage rating is produced by both the plating that gets hit (and has to resist with minimal spalling and oxidising) by the initial arc, and the distance that the two sides of the open switch are apart.

So no, voltage and amperage can not be interchanged in this case.

Going over the rated voltage may damage the contact-pads by more powerful arcing during the opening and closeing of the switch. This will lead to higher resistance, and thereby higher temperatures in the closed switch. If the current is very low, heating won't be aproblem.

Going over the rated voltage by a big margin may lead to continuous arcing (or arcing every time the voltage spikes a little) which will damage your circuit, damage the contact pads badly, and will lead to heating/flame.

Going over the rated current will lead to heating in any case.

Both, surpassing the rated voltage and surpassing the rated current, may lead to sticking of the switch, i.e. a form of welding-together of the contacts. Depending on the specifics of the mechanism, you may not be able to open the switch again.

Comment: So, these ratings are seperate?  As in these are just the maximum ratings for VDC and amperage regardless of one another?

Comment: i added the what-ifs to my answer.